# django Subquery annotate ForeignKey

Tags: django, queryset

Есть две модели:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="GUID книги", unique=True, editable=False)
....
```

и

```
class User_Book(models.Model):  # Книга, когда либо читаемая пользователем.
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, editable=True)
    on_bookShelf = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'На книжной полке', default=True)
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Время последнего добавления на полку',
                                    null=True)

....
```

Мне нужно сделать annotate для всех книг пользователя, чтобы было время добавления в итоговом QuerySet

Делаю так:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
bookshelf = Book.objects.filter(user_book__user=u, user_book__on_bookShelf=True)
bookshelf = bookshelf.annotate(add_time = Subquery(User_Book.objects.get(user=u, book=OuterRef('pk')).add_time)))
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and
> may only be used in a subquery.

Что я делаю не так, не пойму?
Уже приходят мысли сделать через обычный raw SQL и Join, по моему так быстрее будет.

Comment: Ваша модель позволяет создать несколько записей для тех же user и book. Какую дату нужно выбрать в таком случае? Или это просто пропущенное ограничение на уникальность пары `(user, book)` и на самом деле всегда одна такая связь?

Comment: @RomanKonoval там в Meta для User_Book есть unique_together, не позволяет :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось проще.
Великая сила Managers в django позволяет вот так сделать:

```
 Book.objects.filter(user_book__user=u, user_book__on_bookShelf=True).values('title', 'user_book__add_time')
```